# Javascript event when writing in number field

Tags: javascript

I have the following form element

```
< input type="number" name="abc" id="abc" value="10" min="10" onclick="runFunction()" onchange="runFunction()" >
```

When I click on the up/down arrows at the end of the number field, the function runs. I also want the function to run when the user types in a number, but the function runs only if I click outside the field after typing.

Is there a way to set an event that runs as the user types in the numbers?

Comment: you can use `oninput` instead of onclick and onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add the 'oninput' event to your HTML input tag.

```
<input type="number" name="abc" id="abc" value="10" min="10" onclick="runFunction()" onchange="runFunction()" oninput="runFunction()">
```

**Note: You may want to remove the other events, otherwise you will have simultaneous events being triggered.**

```
<input type="number" name="abc" id="abc" value="10" min="10" oninput="runFunction()">
```

More info about 'oninput' here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Comment: Actually the 'oninput' event is better because the 'onkeypress' will trigger an event even if the key is not a number... I just edited my answer to reflect that.. Thanks clod9353!